# Which element should handle data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, there are 2 components:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    comments=[1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Comments />
    )
  }
}

class Comments extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        /* show comments */
    )
  }
}
```

and I want to show only even comments. Should I put sorting function into App and send prepared array to Comments or send entire array and let Comments sort it by itself?

Comment: It largely depends on *why* you want to filter it like that.

Answer (score 0):

That's a design decision. But usually the View should just display the Model without any logic. That means your parent component `App` should filter the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want your *Comments Component* to reacts. If there aren't many function to perform and you want to make *App component* to react as ***container*** and comments as ***controlled component***, you go do it like this:

```
import React from "react";

class Comments extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { comments } = this.props;
    return comments.map(comment => <h1>{comment}</h1>);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    comments: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  };
  render() {
    const { comments } = this.state;
    let evenComments = comments.filter(item => item % 2 === 0);
    return <Comments comments={evenComments} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the sorting logic in `APP.jsx` file.

like this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    comments=[1, 2, 3, 4]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Comments type={return this.state.comments.filter((comment) => comment%2 === 0)} /> 
    )
  }
}

class Comments extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        /* show comments */
    )
  }
}
```